# Obtaining text output from Fortify sourceanalyzer command line

Tags: c#, security, command-line, teamcity, fortify

Related to question: [Fortify command line usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925173/fortify-command-line-usage)

I would like to perform a nightly Fortify scan of my .NET solution, triggered by TeamCity's command line runner. I want to post up my own custom summary of the results to a web page.

The key information I want is the number of issues per level of criticality.

I have previously used the -f command-line switch for use with the Audit Workbench client, but the resulting .FPR file looks difficult to parse and interpret manually.

I'm using `Fortify Static Code Analyzer 5.15.0.0060` and there does not appear to be a `-format` option that I can use to specify text.

Is there a way to obtain the numbers of issues found by the scan?

Comment: Are you using the ReportGenerator utility?

Comment: Not yet (hadn't heard of it), but after reading your message I had a quick Google and I've just seen that ReportGenerator may be able to turn an FPR file into a custom-formatted report, based on a template. This might be exactly what I need! I'll post back with results. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Thanks so much, LaJmOn. Using the default template (without specifying -template to ReportGenerator) I can get a nice XML file with an IssueListing section that gives me the counts for each group. This is exactly what I needed. If you post this as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: I have some trouble in report generator too. maybe you could try FPRUtility.bat, BIRTReportGenerator.cmd, and ReportGenerator.bat. all of them is in the path %Fortify%/bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ReportGenerator utility. It was specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you - is any documentation available for this tool? The XML templates don't seem the most intuitive to update. The default template gives me an issue count by category (e.g. 'Dead code: Unused method') but I'd like this breakdown with Fortify Priority Order (Critical, High, Medium etc.) too.