# Create a customized TFS policy to run fortify at check in

Tags: tfs, fortify

I need to create a new checkin policy in TFS to every time that I'm checking code from one specific branch to another run fortify. Any ideas on how to do this? Is there someone that have done this before? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the **custom path policy** (Need TFS Power Tools) which means the policy scopes other policies to specific folders or file types.

More details about how to use this policy, you can refer the link from MSDN: [How to apply check-in policies to only certain branches or folders](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/girishp/2012/02/16/tfs-2010-how-to-apply-check-in-policies-to-only-certain-branches-or-folders/)

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with this. Maybe use the Fortify command line ? However, you can also use a gated build to achieve what you need. You can use "Invoke Process" build activities to make this happen. More detail steps you can refer the answer from AspiringTFSGuru  in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925173/fortify-command-line-usage